# How to show multiple text fields on button click one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add 2-3 text fields on button click one by one, where 'L' is the ID of the textfield. I am trying this code, but instead of using jQuery I want to use simple javascript because I am implementing this code in a Joomla environment.

```
function WrapperScript () {
    JQuery('#wrapper1 button').click(function(){
        for (var i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            var id='#L'+i;
            var setting = JQuery(id).css('display');
            if (setting=='none')
            {
                JQuery(id).css('display', 'block');
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to ADD the textboxes, or SHOW existing ones?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make the same script without using jQuery here is a sample

```
function WrapperScript () {

//use an appropriate getter for the button
var button = document.getElementblahblah

button.onclick = function(){
   for (var i=1;i<=4;i++)
   {
      var id='#L'+i;
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      var setting = element.style.display;

      if ( setting=='none' )
      {
         element.style.display = 'block';
         break;
      }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: don't know any reason but somehow this didn't work on joomla environment

Comment: did you change the button selector? try setting an id to the button (ex. id="txtButton") and change var button = document.getElementById('txtButton')